# Adding columns dynamically to a datatable throws "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatable created using jQuery DataTables, created using a dynamic number of columns:

```
            this.vehiclesDataTable = $("#vehiclesTable").DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"lp>i<"clear">',
            responsive: true,
            data: data,
            columns: this.dynamicColumns
        });
```

and here is the sample data I am passing in for the data:property:

```
[[0,"2016-05-01",0],[0,"2016-06-01",0],[0,"2016-07-01",0],[0,"2016-08-01",1],
[0,"2016-09-01",1],[0,"2016-10-01",0],[0,"2016-11-01",0],[0,"2016-12-01",0],
[0,"2017-01-01",0],[0,"2017-02-01",0],[0,"2017-03-01",0],[0,"2017-04-01",0],
[0,"2017-05-01",0]]
```

...and the columns property, with 3 columns matching the data:

```
[{"className":"details-control","sTitle":" ", 
"orderable":false,"data":null,"defaultContent":""," sWidth":"2%", 
"name":"expandCollapseRow"}, {"title":"Date"," sWidth":"100px"},
{"title":"testworks","sWidth":"30px","sClass":"dataTableAlignRight"}]
```

This works fine and creates a valid datatable. However, when trying to re-bind this table to data that has MORE than 3 columns - many times I get the error:

> ***"Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"***

even though I completely flush the datatable first using:

```
        vehiclesDataTable.clear();
        $('#vehiclesTable').empty();
```

CodePen Example:
    [Dynamic columns using DataTables](https://codepen.io/danshultz11/pen/rGPqdo/)

Comment: Did you redefine the *columns* option too? I don't know anything about *datatable* but I can figure out that it relies on it to determine some properties of each row cells and it doesn't expect more columns than explicitly declared.

Comment: Yes, the columns are reset to exactly match the number of columns in the data.  The first time through, the table is always drawn successfully, no matter how many columns are passed...  I only get this error the second time the table is drawn using MORE columns than the previous table

Comment: In that case I think it must be an error in plugin implementation so the only solution is to debug and fix it. Even thought I imagine that, as a workarround, is pretty possible that, if you define a large enough number of columns at first time (even providing empty data to immediately reset and fill with actual first data), you could avoid this problem.

Comment: Btw. Can you provide a reproducible example? Better jsfiddle or similar. I tried to compose your code with GitHub's version of DataTables with no luck.

Comment: CodePen Example Added to question https://codepen.io/danshultz11/pen/rGPqdo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [your example](https://codepen.io/danshultz11/pen/rGPqdo/), I see you are re-instantiating the plugin over already instantiated jQuery/DOM object.

So here concurs two issues:

1. Second time you call `createDataTable()` function, `$("#vehiclesTable")` selector matches the same DOM object, but its contents have been altered by first *DataTable* instantiation and, I don't know how, but it's pretty possible that *DataTable* uses original container contents in some way (or maybe it simply drops it, but you are filling it in your html with a *thead* and *tbody* nodes which, definitively, is not what second instantiation will find.
2. As I said, you are instantiating *DataTable* **again** over same DOM (yet -by DataTable- enhanced/messed) object. So things should go wrong for sure...

I don't know if *DataTables* plugin has **an API** function to alter its content (and heading confguration, etc...) which is what I thought you were trying to achieve. But at [first glance](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) I don't think so (and if there is, it would brobably be more complicated than simply drop that table and replace it by new fresh one.

So, probably, the best solution would be to simply drop existing table and (as you in fact were doing anyway) instantiate again *DataTables* plugin from the scratch **but over newly created fresh DOM object**.

That is (simplifying a bit...) replace:

```
vehiclesDataTable = $("#vehiclesTable").DataTable(...);
```

by

```
vehiclesDataTable = $("<table></table>"); // Insert here thead and tbody if really necessary.
$("#vehiclesTable").replaceWith(vehiclesDataTable);
vehiclesDataTable.attr("id", "vehiclesTable"); // (Added after replacement to avoid two elements having same id)
vehiclesDataTable.DataTable(...);
```

This way, every time you call `createDataTable()` function, all old stuff is discarded and no side effect should take place.

Comment: Nicely done - the only difference was the $("<table></table>") assignment needed to also include the id="vehiclesTable" attribute.  I saved this fix in the original Pen.

Comment: Another slight tweak necessary, DataTables wraps each table in a <div> named id="[tablename]_wrapper".  We need to blow this away and replace it with our original table.  So $("vehiclesTable").replaceWith() needs to be $("vehiclesTable_wrapper").replaceWith(), or else we get multiple repeating footers

Comment: You're right! I remember I thought in th id, but now I see I missed at the end… I will fix it lates (I'm writting from my smartphone now). That being said, I did it this way to minimice the changes for the sake of understandability. But it would be much better to use a container (such a simple div) and drop and rebuild its contents from createDataTable()

Comment: Done (even a bit later). Anyway, that is just for the sake of making minimal changes to your original code. As I said, it would be much better to use a container captured single time and replace its contents every time. Relying on ids when you can avoid it, is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Your answer really worked , but as suggested in the comments need to slight tweaks for header and footers